# Obtaining 0th column data frame information in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

How would you access the date column on the left here of this data frame?

```
> data
GMT
                Rate
2005-02-28 0.48326866256
2005-04-30 0.64922340405
2005-05-31 0.70036043096
2005-06-30 0.72051442515
.
.
.
```

If I type,

```
data[ , 1]
```

… it gives me the rate column. As expected.

If I use,

```
data[ , 0]
```

... it doesn’t work. And I get 'Error: subscript out of bounds'.

But if I do,

```
data[1 , 0]
```

... I get back the first date. 2005-02-28.

---

This seems a bit contradictory to me that I can't pull up data[ , 0], given that I can pull up data[ , 1] and can also pull up data[1 , 0].

How do I pull up that those date values? And why doesn't data[ , 0] work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no 0th column. What you are probably seeing, rather, are *row names*. You can access them via:

```
rownames(data) # for a matrix-like object
row.names(data) # for a data.frame
```

But either will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit new to R and this was frustrating me.

Answer (score 0):

First a general note, R does not have 0-indexing, so there will never be a column 0. Depending on the data type (which you get with str(data)), you will get the dates via rownames(data) (if it is indeed a matrix or data.frame), or via index (if it is a time series, as seems likely).

Answer (score 0):

There is no 0th column its called `rownames` like we have names for columns, we have names for rows.

Showing example for `iris` dataset

```
  rownames(iris)
```

In your case: `rownames(data)`

Instead you can create another dataframe `df` where you can append `rownames` as First column and then the whole dataset, shown below for `iris` dataset.

```
  df <- data.frame(cbind(First_col=rownames(iris), iris))
  head(df)

  #  First_col Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
  # 1         1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
  # 2         2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
  # 3         3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
  # 4         4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
  # 5         5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
  # 6         6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

To avoid printing of `rownames` of `df` created here

```
  print(head(df), row.names=F)
  # First_col Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
  #         1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
  #         2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
  #         3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
  #         4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
  #         5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
  #         6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

You can implement the same for your dataset.